# Simple Manual Lexer in Haskell

Tags: beginner, haskell, lexical-analysis

As a beginner exercise, I made small manual lexer that recognizes three types of inputs:

- integers:  `/[-]?[0-9]+/`
- strings, inside double quotes, with backslash escaping
- *nil*

using only Data.Char and Data.Maybe.

I would have wanted to do something that looks like this

```hs
parse s =  tryParseInteger s
        OR tryParseString s
        OR tryParseNil
```

where each tryParse* would return a `(Maybe MyToken)` and a failing case (= `Nothing`) would continue to the next tryParse*.
But I didn't find a clean way to do it.

So here it goes:

```hs
import Data.Char;
import Data.Maybe;

data MyToken = MyNil
             | MyNumber Int
             | MyString String
             deriving (Show)

tryParse :: String -> Maybe MyToken
tryParse "nil" = Just MyNil
tryParse (c : t)
  -- Ignoring white space and parse the tail
  | isSpace c = tryParse t
tryParse s = tryParseNumber s


tryParseNumber :: String -> Maybe MyToken
tryParseNumber s = case (parseNum s) of
                     Just v -> Just $ MyNumber v
                     Nothing -> tryParseString s


tryParseString :: String -> Maybe MyToken
tryParseString ('"':t) = fmap MyString (parseInsideString t)
tryParseString _ = Nothing


parseInsideString :: String -> Maybe String
parseInsideString ('\\':'"':cs) = fmap ('"':) (parseInsideString cs)
parseInsideString ('"':_) = Just ""
parseInsideString (c:cs) = fmap (c:) (parseInsideString cs)
parseInsideString _ = Nothing


parseNum :: String -> Maybe Int
parseNum ('-':xs) = fmap (\x -> -x) (parseNum xs)
parseNum cs@(c:_)
  | isDigit c = foldl step Nothing cs
  | otherwise = Nothing
    where step acc c
           | isDigit c = Just ((10 * fromMaybe 0 acc) + (digitToInt c))
           | otherwise = acc


main = print $ tryParse "\"abcd\\\"efgh\""
```

Answer (score 2):

> I would have wanted to do something that looks like this
>
> ```
> parse s =  tryParseInteger s
>         OR tryParseString s
>         OR tryParseNil
> ```

`OR` is `<|>`:

```
tryParse :: String -> Maybe MyToken
tryParse = tryParse' . dropWhile isSpace
  where
    tryParse' s
      =   MyNumber <$> parseNumber s
      <|> tryParseString s
      <|> tryParseNil s

tryParseNil :: String -> Maybe MyToken
tryParseNil "nil" = Just MyNil
tryParseNil _ = Nothing
```